# C++/C: Prepend length to Char[] in bytes (binary/hex)

Tags: c++, c, type-conversion, udp, hex

I'm looking to send UDP datagrams from a client, to a server, and back.

The server needs to add a header to each datagram (represented as a `char[]`) in byte format, which I've struggled to find examples of. I know how to send it as actual text characters, but I want to send it perhaps as "effectively" binary form (eg, if the `length` were to be `40 bytes` then I'd want to prepend `0x28` , or the 2 byte unsigned equivalent, rather than as '0028' in ASCII `char` form or similar, which would be 4 bytes instead of a potential 2.

As far as I can work out my best option is below:

```
unsigned int length = dataLength; //length of the data received

char test[512] = { (char)length };
```

Is this approach valid, or will it cause problems later?

Further, this gives me a hard limit of 255 if I'm not mistaken. How can I best represent it as 2 bytes to extend my maximum length.

EDIT: I need the length of each datagram to be prepended because I will be building each datagram into a larger frame, and the recipient needs to be able to take the frame apart into each information element, which I think means I should need the length included so the recipient and work out where each element ends and the next begins

Comment: If the receiver expects this length as ASCII, then sending it as binary will cause errors in the receiver. Also there is the endian-problem of sending binary numbers.

Comment: Finally, UDP has built in message length in the protocol

Comment: I'm also developing the receiver, so will be able to convert at the opposite end. Sorry to ask, but could you please explain what you mean by the "endian-problem of sending binary numbers"?

Also I know UDP has it built in, but the requirements for this project involve adding my own length and other header information, sorry :).

Comment: @GeorgeG google "endianness"

Comment: I would've thought this was unlikely to cause problems if both ends of the connection are controlled by me (as I'm developing both client and server). Correct me if I'm wrong please! :)

Comment: Oh.. Information I should probably have included from the beginning: I need the length of each datagram to be prepended because I will be building each datagram into a larger frame, and the recipient needs to be able to take the frame apart into each information element, which I think means I should need the length included so the recipient and work out where each element ends and the next begins.

Comment: [Edit] your question to contain necessary information

Comment: Converting to and from big-endian is still highly recommended to save you the countless unfortold headaches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need something like this:

```
  char somestring[] = "Hello World!";
  char sendbuffer[1000];

  int length = strlen(somestring);
  sendbuffer[0] = length % 0xff;         // put LSB of length
  sendbuffer[1] = (length >> 8) & 0xff;  // put MSB of length

  strcpy(&sendbuffer[2], somestring);    // copy the string right after the length
```

`sendbuffer` is the buffer that will be sent; I fixed it to a maximum length of 1000 allowing for strings up to an length of 997 beeing sent (1000 - 2 bytes for the length - 1 byte for NUL terminator).

`LSB` means *least significant byte* and `MSB` means *most significant byte*. Here we put the LSB first and the MSB second, this convention is called *little endian*, the other way round would be *big endian*. You need to be sure that on the receiver side that the length is correctly decoded. If the architecture on the receiver side has an other endianness than the sender, the length on the receiver side may be decoded wrong depending on the code. Google "endianness" for more details.

`sendbuffer` will look like this in memory:

```
 0x0c 0x00 0x48 0x65 0x6c 0x6c ...
|   12    |'H' |'e' |'l' |'l '| ...
```

---

```
  //... Decoding (assuming short is a 16 bit type on the receiver side)

  // first method (won't work if endiannnes is different on receiver side)
  int decodedlength = *((unsigned short*)sendbuffer);       

  // second method (endiannness safe)
  int decodedlength2 = (unsigned char)sendbuffer[0] | (unsigned char)sendbuffer[1] << 8;


  char decodedstring[1000];
  strcpy(decodedstring, &sendbuffer[2]);
```

Possible optimisation:

If the majority of the strings you send have a length shorter than 255, you can optimize and not prepending systematically two bytes but only one byte most of the time, but that's another story.

Comment: This looks good! I'll test it my end and make sure I understand it before ticking the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Note that length does not include nul-terminator. And you actually do not need to transfer nul-terminator - it can be appended on the receiver side.